# Array modified by function without return

Tags: python

First of all, I am sorry if this question has already been answered, but I really struggle to understand.

My problem is that I pass an array to a function and my array is modified globally without return :

```
import random

ARRAY_SIZE = 10

def square(array):
    for  index in range(len(array)):
        array[index] = array[index]**2

array = {}
for index in range(ARRAY_SIZE):
    array[index] = random.randint(0,100)

print("Before power : ")
print(array)
square(array)
print("After power : ")
print(array)
```

The output is :

```
Before power :
{0: 62, 1: 1, 2: 47, 3: 11, 4: 49, 5: 100, 6: 85, 7: 100, 8: 26, 9: 76}
After power :
{0: 3844, 1: 1, 2: 2209, 3: 121, 4: 2401, 5: 10000, 6: 7225, 7: 10000, 8: 676, 9: 5776}
```

Conclusion: arrays passed to functions are modified globally.

What confuses me is that single variables passed to functions are not modified globally. As in this example:

```
import random

def square(x):
    x = x ** 2

print("Before power : ")
x = random.randint(0,100)
print(x)
square(x)
print("After power : ")
print(x)
```

Output :

```
Before power :
56
After power :
56
```

Conclusion: Single variables passed to functions without return are not modified globally.

Why does python modify array globally but not single variables?

Comment: `{}` is dictionary (hashmap) in python not array, I am afraid you are coming from java array notation?

Comment: I wrote one article for the same, you check if you find it useful https://probhakar-95.medium.com/are-python-functions-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference-6d28991df1b1

Comment: ```x``` is a local variable created inside the function. It cannot be accessed anywhere else until it is declared global, returned or passed as an argument

Comment: I mistakenly declared a dict while I wanted to declare an array. I fixed that and the conclusions are the same : modificaton in the elements of an array take effect outside functions whereas single variables are not modified outside functions unless global or return are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the use of the term "global" you come to not so wrong conclusions.
There are mutable types like `list` and `dict` and immutable types like `int` and `str`. The former can be changed via the reference that was passed as a function parameter while the latter cannot.

Comment: however I can type x = any_other_number after declaring x with an initial value and that is going to modify x. Did this create a new variable called x in another memory location or did I modify the initial x?

Comment: You just assigned a new value to the old variable. You did not change the value of the object that was assigned to `x` before.

Comment: I just declared a variable x twice in the same file and checked their ids with the function id() and their ids were different. Now, I understand what mutable and unmutable is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between assigning to a variable and modifying an object.

```
x = x ** 2
```

This creates a new number and assigns it to `x`. No objects are modified and no other variables are affected.

```
array[index] = y
```

This modifies `array` by assigning to an index *inside* the list. The change will be visible from any variables which refer to that list.

To make a whole new list without changing `array`:

```
def square(array):
    return [x**2 for x in array]
```

Comment: The bracket-equals notation calls the magic `__setitem__` method, which can technically do anything